# Biber missing libcrypt.so.1 library on Fedora

Tags: installing, biber, linuxfedora

Since upgrading my Fedora system, `biber` no longer runs. It complains that it cannot find the shared library `libcrypt.so.1`.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that Fedora replaced `libcrypt` with another library based on `libxcrypt` which is safer. They provide a compatibility layer for programs that still link to the old library.

All you have to do is install the package `libxcrypt-compat`:

```
sudo dnf install libxcrypt-compat
```